# Problem when dealing with ajax requests in laravel - Status 400

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel

The JavaScript code is below.

```
$.ajaxSetup({ headers: { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': '{{ csrf_token() }}' } });
$.ajax({
  type : 'POST',
  url: 'test',
  data: data,
  success: ...
});
```

The 400 error does not necessarily occur, but only for a very small number of users.
I'm trying to fix the problem, but the laravel log is not output for this 400 error in the first place.
（Status is recorded in Apache log）

```
$message = $this->logBefore($request);
$response = $next($request);
$message .= $this->logAfter($request, $response);
\Log::info($message);
```

Therefore, it is not possible to reproduce the cause of the error of the phenomenon.
To supplement the logs, we have registered global middleware for log output. (Logs out all request contents and response status)
However, the log of 400 status in the above part is not recorded unintentionally. Also, exceptions are not recorded as well.
Why aren't logs being output, and are you not aware of the cause of 400?
For reference, the browser of the user with 400 error is IE11.
(Although it does not necessarily occur in IE11）
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, It seems that the browser's security extension has been affecting.

Answer (score 0):

try to catch the error with the following:

```
fail(function(jqXHR)) {
  console.log(jqXHR.responseJSON.msg);
}
```

Comment: The only error message that can be confirmed on the console is "error Bad Request"